# Changing Edge color with D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am reading a D3 tutorial and am following the code in this link:

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html

I understand the content so far, but am trying to learn more styling by changing different colors. I am trying to change the edge color between the nodes, but this is not working. I know I need to do

```
path.style("stroke", red)
```

for instance. But this changes every edge color as expected.

However, I want to change the color of the edge based on the value in the links array. So, if the links.value is < 1 I want green else I want an orange link. 
I am somewhat stuck I know I need to use

```
.style("stroke", function(d) {if d.value < 1 {return 'green'} else {return 'orange'} });
```

I just can't figure out where to put this in the sample code. I'm just trying to learn by example from some basic D3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the style in the "enter" selection of the edges:

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function(d){ 
        if(d.value < 1) {return 'green'} else {return 'orange'} 
    }) 
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tOBZdHXVrvcAmh9aHlsl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your chain your methods on to the end of:

```
// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

It's approx line 73 of the sample code